# Can i create multiple proxy for a account by using proxy Accounts?

Tags: pallet, proxy

I need to create multiple proxies for an account by using proxy accounts. Can I do it?
if yes can I manage multiple proxies to make transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a proxy with restricted rights and then that account could have a proxy with even more restricted rights I believe.

Or you could have two proxies with one having voting rights and another having staking rights for example.

On polkadot there is a non-trivial deposit at the moment for creating a proxy (this is because it has to set up some state on the chain).

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-proxies